# Dial another phone, access SMS of another phone using IPOD Touch 4

Tags: ipod-touch, sms

I have an IPOD Touch 4 and i was hoping to convert it to a phone. However in india we don't have VOIP support, but my phone "HTC TOUCH" supports Remote Sim. I am looking for an app which can allow my ipod to control my phone and also enable me to make calls thru my ipod by dialing on my phone. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not possibly currently I'm afraid. Certainly, you'd have to have a jailbroken Touch as a starting point. No way you'd be able to do this on a stock iPod Touch. Even then, I'm not aware of anything out there that will do this.

Comment: what about Reverse tethering? I want to connect to my HTC Touch's GPRS connection using IPOD touch?

Comment: That may be more likely, but again you'll have to jailbreak the device at the very least. There's a lot more information about simple tethering to share a GPRS/Edge/3G connection out there, but all require jailbreaking as a first step. The only other option would be if you can configure your HTC Touch to become a Wifi basestation for tethering purposes. I'm sure this is possible. The iPod touch would then connect using either bluetooth or Wifi, but that would shift the emphasis to the HTC Touch needing a change, which could make it much easier.